# MPMoviePlayerController - catching network errors when loading a movie

Tags: mpmovieplayercontroller

Is there a way of catching exceptions (particularly for network errors
/ no connection available) when using a MPMoviePlayerController?

I am particularly concerned that once an instance of the player is initialised with `initWithURL:` you have no way of knowing whether the movie load has failed for some reason.

I have reviewed the available documentation and realise I can get a
notification for loadState changes through

```
moviePlayerLoadStateChanged:(NSNotification*)notification.
```

Problem is the loadState constants available don't cater for error handling:

```
MPMovieLoadStateUnknown
MPMovieLoadStatePlayable
MPMovieLoadStatePlaythroughOK
MPMovieLoadStateStalled
```

(in case you are wondering, MPMovieLoadStateStalled this doesn't get called during network errors for some reason?)

There's a deprecated `MPMoviePlayerContentPreloadDidFinishNotification` that provides a userInfo dictionary with an "error" key but nothing for iOS 3.2 and above.

Any help would be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the end I got this sorted by subscribing to MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification and watching for MPMovieFinishReasonPlaybackError.

More details here https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/MediaPlayer/Reference/MPMoviePlayerController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006953-CH3-SW17

Comment: Hey, could you add a sample code? The apple documentation lacks examples, and I can't figure out how to do what you recommend.