# How does MPMoviePlayerController react to HTTP 404 and 504 error?

Tags: ios, mpmovieplayercontroller

I couldn't find any information in the reference page of MPMoviePlayerController or in the Apple Developer forum. Do any of you know what will happen if we the server throws 404 or 504 back to the player while streaming?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We set up a web server to test this, and found out:

- 404: the player will skip the fragment, request and play the next fragment (so users will see frame skip in the movie). The same behavior if you throw 503 at the player.
- 504: the player won't request any other fragment, and will terminate the playback session when running out of buffer.

Comment: In my experience, the whole video didn't play and the player stayed black.

Answer (score 0):

The MPMoviePlayerController relies on notifications to report any events or errors.

[MPMoviePlayerController - catching network errors when loading a movie](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4150085/mpmovieplayercontroller-catching-network-errors-when-loading-a-movie)

Comment: What I'd like to know is the behavior of the player when these errors happen, i.e. if it terminates or still plays.

Comment: It obviously can't play if there is an error. I don't think it will dismiss the view, though.

Comment: please look at what we found above. The player will skip frame if error 404 or 503, and terminate if error 504.